# Music Organization via command line?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, music

I have a pretty decent library of songs I was able to grab from my Google Music account. However, there is no structure to them right now, only a mass of songs in a single folder.

Is there a command line only tool that can read through these, and tag/sort them for me? I know there are tons of UI based tools for this, but my server is headless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find [beets](http://beets.io/), which is pretty much exactly what I could have hoped for. It's a command line tool , written in Python, that will tag, sort, and clean up music libraries for you. the plugin possibilities are also pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [exiftool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) to read the ID3 tags from your music files. Then use this information in a script to rename/move your files into a more readable structure.

```
$ exiftool Martin_Garrix-Animals_\(Original_Mix\).mp3 
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.00
File Name                       : Martin Garrix - Animals (Original Mix).mp3
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 12 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:01:13 11:10:16-02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2016:01:14 10:03:18-02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:12:27 00:39:21-02:00
File Permissions                : rwxrwxr-x
File Type                       : MP3
File Type Extension             : mp3
MIME Type                       : audio/mpeg
MPEG Audio Version              : 1
Audio Layer                     : 3
Audio Bitrate                   : 320 kbps
Sample Rate                     : 44100
Channel Mode                    : Joint Stereo
MS Stereo                       : On
Intensity Stereo                : Off
Copyright Flag                  : True
Original Media                  : True
Emphasis                        : None
ID3 Size                        : 57933
Band                            : Martin Garrix
Album                           : Animals
Beats Per Minute                : 128
Genre                           : Progressive House
Track                           : 1
Year                            : 2013
User Defined URL                : http://www.edmexqlusiv.com/
Picture MIME Type               : image/jpeg
Picture Type                    : Front Cover
Picture Description             : 
Picture                         : (Binary data 55457 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Title                           : Animals (Original Mix)
Artist                          : Martin Garrix
Comment                         : Downloaded from
Date/Time Original              : 2013
Duration                        : 0:05:04 (approx)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hacked together this script, which should pretty much do what you intend. It reads the ID3 tags of each file in the current directory (`cd` to the directory with all the music files first), greps the artist, album and title tag, and moves the file to `artist/album/title.extension`, creating the folder structure if necessart.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Install id3 command line tool, if not installed
if [ -z "`dpkg -s id3 | grep 'Status: install'`" ]; then
    sudo apt-get install id3
fi
IFS=$'\n'
for f in *; do
    #Skip directories
    [ -d "$f" ] && continue
    tags=($(id3 -l "$f" | sed -re 's/\s{2,}([^:])/\n\1/g' | egrep ':.+'))
    for l in ${tags[@]}; do
        [ -n "`echo $l | egrep '^Title'`" ] && TITLE="`echo $l | sed -re 's/^.*?: //'`"
        [ -n "`echo $l | egrep '^Artist'`" ] && ARTIST="`echo $l | sed -re 's/^.*?: //'`"
        [ -n "`echo $l | egrep '^Album'`" ] && ALBUM="`echo $l | sed -re 's/^.*?: //'`"
    done
    mkdir -p "$ARTIST/$ALBUM"
    mv "$f" "$ARTIST/$ALBUM/$TITLE.$(echo $f | sed -re 's/.*\.([^.]*$)/\1/g')"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

for the record, I found mussort which is in the repos and does this simple task of sorting by Artist/Album using command line. Just need to type mussort . in the folder. Not that it will also rename the files and replace spaces with _.

More info: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mussort.1.html

alternatively, you can use `exiftool`:  `exiftool '-Directory<${Artist;}/${Album;}' "$filepath"`